# How to make ~ work for en-dashes?

Tags: line-breaking, tilde

I have a German [LaTeX-document](http://fuz.su/~fuz/bbdcm) that tries to implement German en-dash line-breaking rules with `~` like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\begin{document}
\fraklines\frakfamily\noindent
Bestimmtes: von ihm gewu"st h"atten. Wir waren freilich --~die einzige
Neugierde, die uns: erf"ullte~-- immer bestrebt,
\end{document}
```

Apparently, LaTeX seems to ignore the `~` after *freilich*. In the PDF-output (linked above) on page 4 near the end of the left column, you can clearly see a line-break between *freulich –* and *die einzige*. Is there a way to fix this issue?

I am using the `german` package and the Koma script with the `scrartcl` class.

Comment: Do not use `german`, use package `babel` with the option `german` (or rather `ngerman`).

Comment: @Johannes_B I thought german was an alias for babel with the german option?

Comment: Hi there, I've completed the snippet to a MWE such that people can directly copy paste your example and try it out. Please prefer doing so for the future questions.

Comment: @percusse Thank you for your help. I was already making a MWE while you edited the code, I shortened it even further to show only the relevant things.

Comment: logically, the line break after *freilich* seems correct -- the en-dashes here are acting like parentheses, with a beginning and an end.  not what an english speaker/writer is used to seeing, but logical nonetheless.  this is a matter for someone knowledgeable about german typographic traditions, and thus perhaps off topic.

Comment: @barbarabeeton In fact, there should be a line break right after freilich, but TeX breaks after the en-dash which is wrong according to German orthography rules (line break may not occur on the side of the sentence-part encapsulated by the en-dash).

Comment: interesting!  latex appears to be applying "different rules" to a "nobreak" following a hyphen (or multiple hyphens).  if i change the input to `... \mbox{--}~...` it doesn't break.  trying this with plain tex *doesn't* break, with or without an `\hbox`, so i infer it's something in the latex definitions that is causing the unexpected result.  you might want to submit this as a possible latex bug.  shall i add an "answer" showing my plain tex code?

Comment: @barbarabeeton That would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

converting the example in the original question to plain tex demonstrates that plain tex
tries a lot harder to avoid a break after the en-dash.  here's my test.

```
\hsize=3.615in
%\hsize=3.62in
%\hsize=3.63in

\noindent
Bestimmtes: von ihm gewu\ss t h\"atten. Wir waren freilich --~die einzige
Neugierde, die uns: erf\"ullte~-- immer bestrebt,

\bigskip

\noindent
Bestimmtes: von ihm gewu\ss t h\"atten. Wir waren freilich \hbox{--}~die einzige
Neugierde, die uns: erf\"ullte~-- immer bestrebt,

\bye
```

with `\hsize` at 3.615in, the break is after *freilich*.

at 3.62in, tex gives up, and in the case without the `\hbox`, does break after
the first en-dash.

at 3.63in, there's enough space on the first line for *die*, so the break follows that.

so the application of the penalty where `~` follows a hyphen (or multiples, as for en-dash)
is not absolute, but much more loosely observed with latex.  (why the break occurs with
plain tex requires more digging, but i haven't time just now to do that.)

moral of story: if it's absolutely required that there never be a break following an
en-dash, pack it in a box before the `~`.

Comment: I defined a macro `\newcommand\gs{\mbox{--}\xspace}` and substituted it for `--`. Works like a charm!